# Error running win32yank in neovim, Invalid value for argument cmd: win32yank.exe

Tags: ubuntu, lua, wsl-2, neovim

I have a problem and it is that I put win32yank in my nvim configuration to share the clipboard, the bad thing is that it gives me the following error:

```
Error detected while processing function provider#clipboard#Call[6]..3[15]..<SNR>25_try_cmd:
line    1:
E475: Invalid value for argument cmd: 'win32yank.exe' is not executable
```

**Maybe the error may be in lua, or ubuntu, if you could tell me a way to test the win32yank from the terminal and know that it is not the problem, it would help me a lot**

You can also see it in the following screenshot

[image]

**this happens when I try to copy something in neovim**

**this is my neovim configuration, in this case i passed it to lua, but it is practically the same**:

```
local o = vim.o
local wo = vim.wo

wo.nu = true
wo.rnu = true
o.clipboard = "unnamedplus"

o.expandtab = true
o.tabstop = 4
o.shiftwidth = 4

vim.g.clipboard = {
    name = "win32yank-wsl",
    copy = {
         ["+"] = "win32yank.exe -i --crlf",
         ["*"] = "win32yank.exe -i --crlf"
    },
    paste = {
        ["+"] = "win32yank.exe -o --lf",
        ["*"] = "win32yank.exe -o --lf"
    },
    cache_enabled = false
}
```

[image]
**Also to clarify everything, download the win32yank, just as I did to configure it with my previous version of neovim, and use the following command:**

```
sudo ln -s ~/.config/nvim/win32yank.exe /usr/bin/win32yank
```

**which when executing it did not give me any error**
**you can see that my win32yank is in the nvim folder of .config, as in the ln command**
[image]

**I also add my checkhealth to see that the clipboard is supposedly fine**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would look at [Neovim's FAQ](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-the-windows-clipboard-from-wsl), it has information which fixed my issue.

First check if you are able to execute your win32yank.exe from the command line; you should see a usage statement. If you don't see it, you might want to use the win32yank version that comes in Window's Neovim install.

However in my case, running this fixed things (with `~/bin` being in my `$PATH`):

```
curl -sLo/tmp/win32yank.zip https://github.com/equalsraf/win32yank/releases/download/v0.0.4/win32yank-x64.zip
unzip -p /tmp/win32yank.zip win32yank.exe > /tmp/win32yank.exe
chmod +x /tmp/win32yank.exe
mv /tmp/win32yank.exe ~/bin
```

After doing this, you shouldn't need to set the `vim.g.clipboard` variable.

Sorry if this is not very helpful, this is one of my first posts.

Answer (score 0):

I use WSL `neovim` everyday, and it works great.

In addition to Ethan A's reply I have some to add.

The only think you should have to do is the download the `win32yank.exe`, move to the correct place of your install as described.

But I do set the `vim.o.clipboard` in my config like so:

```lua
vim.o.clipboard = 'unnamedplus'
```

Copy paste between vim and everything else (for [WSL clipboard usage](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-the-windows-clipboard-from-wsl)).

And that should be it. Delete all your other config stuff with the clipboard as it should be unneeded.